# After submitting the web page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

When I started working on a web page with JS, I add a jQuery function that chackes if the data that the user inserted is correct, and returning false (`return false;`), and the form did not refresh the page. Now, after adding AJAX, the form refreshes and I don't know why. Here is my JS code:

```
<script>
        $("form").submit(function(){
            // in this area I have a lot of IF's that checks if everything is currect, this area worked and did not make the problem until I added the AJAX.

        if(allow && style){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "join.php",
                    data: { name: name.val(), url: url.val(), email: email.val(), country: country.val(), language: language.val(), age: age.val(), image: image.val(), type: style.val()}
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    // Success.
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert( "ERROR. Resubmiting the form." );
                    //$("form").submit();
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

In the IF's area, the JS checks if the inserted text is currect and adds a red border for the ones who not. the page refreshes only when everything is currect, when `allow` and `style` are `true`.

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools for errors; if there's a problem with the code before the `return false;` line that means it never gets executed then the form will submit.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?  They have changed how it is used.  the call backs done and fail are not used any more. [Deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Though the link is to ajax, search for the deprecated.

Comment: @alexmac, I'm using 1.10.2

Comment: ok, well your call backs .fail and .done are no longer used as per the dep notices.  go read the link I pointed to.

Comment: @Alex. it's complete, success and error that have been deprecated since 1.8 NOT done and fail.

Comment: VladGincher, I don't see anything wrong with your code. This usually happens when there are JS errors. Please check your browser console for JS erros and tell us what you got.

Answer (score -2):

You should probably add [event.preventdefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to the beginning of your submit function. Also add the event as parameter.
Like so:

```
  $("form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 // in this area I have a lot of IF's that checks if everything is currect, this area worked and did not make the problem until I added the AJAX.

        if(allow && style){
```

This stops the form from following the action and refreshing the page, no you can just submit the post via `$("form").submit();`

EDIT: This should fix it, there might me some syntax errors but you should be alright.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    // in this area I have a lot of IF's that checks if everything is currect, this area worked and did not make the problem until I added the AJAX.

    if (allow && style) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "join.php",
            data: { name: name.val(), url: url.val(), email: email.val(), country: country.val(), language: language.val(), age: age.val,(), image: image.val(), type: style.val()},
            success: function (data) {
            // succes code here
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("ERROR. Resubmiting the form.");
            //$("form").submit();
        }

    });

    }

    return false;
})
;
```

Comment: You could also add `javascript:void(0)` to the forms `action` attribute

Comment: Try to add `debugger;` just after the if like :`if(allow && style){debugger;` When you open the page with chrome does it stop and give you the debug mode or does it just load as usual?

Comment: @EliantenHolder, It just refreshes the page.

Comment: @VladGincher If you are using chrome then that means that `if(allow && style)` is not true (just a check to be sure, when you place the `debugger;` just before the if statement then it should block.). If that is the case then it would be a smart idea to check the value of allow and style (with the same debugger; just use the chrome devtools to get the value just before the if statement).

Comment: The Jquery version deprecated .done and .fail they should be inside the ajax block. Busy at the moment but read the jQuery docs and there was an answer last week that had the same exact issue.